# Web base Video player with Audio Track Number

Tags: html5-video, jwplayer, vlc, video.js

I'd like to ask if there is a web base video player that can play the different audio track of a video file.

Same as desktop application of VLC.

[DESKTOP VLC SAMPLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFjDH.png)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JwPlayer 7 (Premium license) is able to play multiple audio track if you use HLS protocol (.m3u8 playlist).

From the Docs: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1761348

> The labels for these options are based on the M3U8 file, using the
>   NAME attribute.
>
> Servers like Wowza Media Server, Microsoft Azure, and Unified
>   Streaming Platform all support rendering of playlists with alternate
>   audio out of the box.

Demo: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/toolbox/hlsv4-audio-tracks/